# regular expression in python for 'month year'

Tags: python, regex

`'\b\[a-bA-B]{4,10}\s\w{4}\b'` is this the regular expression for 'may 2013' or any such format date in python?

```
import re
regex=re.compile('\b\[a-z]{4-10}\s\w{4}\b')
for line in text:
    list = regex.findall(line)
    for w in list:
        print w
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex pattern for a date format like `may 2013` is the following:

```
re.compile('[a-zA-Z]+\s+\d{4}')
```

Also, you can retrieve the month or year, by using group names, with the following code snippet:

```
regex = re.compile('(?P<month>[a-zA-Z]+)\s+(?P<year>\d{4})')
m = regex.search('may 2013')
print(m.group('month'), m.group('year'))
```

Comment: your regex will  match `dfdbdfbfbfbJan 2013`

Comment: Several regex patterns exist for matching date formats with month and year. For example, the pattern you suggest in your answer to match a month (\w{3}) will only match words of a length of 3 characters. Thus, this will not match months like december or november. For more accuracy, the response of @hwnd is the more adapted.

Answer (score 1):

What about this

```
re.compile(r'\w{3}\s+[0-9]{4}')
```

- `\w{3}` match any word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` three times
- `\s+` match any white space character `[\r\n\t\f ]`
- `[0-9]{4}` match a single character present in the list below Exactly 4 times

Answer (score 0):

Extending last answer further. Regex below is able to find month in digit too.

```
(?P<month>([a-zA-Z]+)|(\d{2}))\s+(?P<year>\d{4})
```

Like these two:

1. 02 2018
2. july 2018